# An error of "ERROR PYTHONPATH"

Tags: ros-diamondback, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to make my ROS system clean by not having this one error. The error as I pasted below after
invoking the command "roswtf". How should I go about this?

Output:

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR PYTHONPATH [/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/unstable/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src:] 
is invalid: Multiple roslib directories in PYTHONPATH (there should only be one)
================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
```

Thanks in advance..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9148/an-error-of-%22error-pythonpath%22/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-21**:
Please don't put [SOLVED] in the title.  Also, don't mark every question as a community wiki, there is no reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not set correctly. It should never mix multiple distributions.

When you follow the [environment setup instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu#cturtle.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup), make sure you only source one version of `setup.bash` in your `~/.bashrc`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-21**:
The first 2 lines are commented, no effect at all.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-21**:
In my ~/.bashrc file, they are correct I think as the related lines are like this:
#source /opt/ros/cturtle/setup.sh
#source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
source /home/shah/ni/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash